# Getting ORA-01002 error when saving the page

Tags: 2011, 2011-sp1

I am getting this error some times when saving the page in Tridion 2011 Sp1.

We are suing Oracle Database and recently I had run maintenance jobs to rebuild the index as as per SDL.

```
Description:
Unable to save Page (tcm: 47-126-64).
ORA-01002: retrieval of order

Error Code:
0x80040000 (-2147221504)

Call Stack:
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32,OracleConnection,IntPtr,OpoSqlValCtx*,Object,String,Boolean)
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError (Int32, Oracle Connection, IntPtr, Object, Boolean)
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.Read ()
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemDataMapper.GetUniquenessConflictsPost(IDataReader)
Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.OrganizationalItemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IOrganizationalItemDataMapper.GetUniquenessConflicts(TcmUri,TcmUri,IDictionary`2)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.GetConflicts (Dictionary`2)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.AssertNoUniquenessConflicts(IDictionary`2)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.OnSaving (SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.OnSaving (SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page.OnSaving (SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save (SaveEventArgs)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save (Boolean)
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save ()
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.VersionedItemFacade.UpdateAndCheckIn(UserContext,String,Boolean,Boolean)
XMLState.Save
Page.Save
```

The time outs are

[image]

Can some one help me how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the description Oracle gives for the ORA-01002 error it almost always points to an issue in the SQL statementexecuted and incorrect cursor usage. But seeing that you get it intermittently I would suspect your database maintenance is lacking and the error is just caused by a query timing out.

You mention you have done maintenance on the database to rebuild the indexes, but you don't mention updating the database statistics, which is one of the biggest requirements to keep your database performing.

An Oracle database (unlike a MS SQL Server one) needs to be maintained manually, as it does not have automatic maintenance. Next to that you should know that the SDL Tridion CMS database is a high volume transactional database, which should give a DBA some idea of what maintenance is required (it is also described in the documentation).

If you haven't read the documentation yet, check out this http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-EDD4185A-1165-491D-9A11-F931534B4877 ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))